# material-table filtering: filterCellStyle backgroundColor not applied to entire row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Material-table filtering: filter cell style's background color is not applied to the entire row. The column created for row selection has its own style and I don't know how to override it.

Code example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-filter-selection-forked-t9vb54?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your `style.css` file:

```
.App
  .MuiTableBody-root .MuiTableRow-root:first-of-type {
  background: #6ABAC9;
}
```

you can also delete this prop:

```
   filterCellStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#6ABAC9"
          }
```

Comment: I'm using this logic with a sticky filter row. This works for any time options={{ filtering: true }}, however, if filtering is false, it does the styling on the first data-row. Please take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-sticky-filter-y9mvtf?file=/src/App.js